# Webform tokens - token to return the 'option value' not 'option text'

Tags: webforms

I am trying to pass the value of fields from one wizard page to another page . I can use the [Webform_submission:values:element_key] to pass most values. However on the select list I want the 'option value' not the 'option text'.
Example using the twig
  Example:
   '#options':
     10: Ten
     20: Twenty
     30: Thirty
     40: Forty
     50: Fifty

**if the second item is selected I want the value "20" not "Twenty"**

Is there a token that will give me the other value?

Answer (score 1):

You need to suffix your token with `:raw`.

@see https://www.drupal.org/project/webform/issues/2990260